# Get percentage between 2 numbers

Tags: php, math, equation, algebra

so I have a poll website, each question has 2 alternatives. Let's say question A has 130 answers on YES and 90 answers on NO, how can i calculate how many percentage chose the YES answer, and how many people chose the NO answer?

I have tried multiple equations for example  but they all end up giving false information. I have been working with this for hours, but math is not really my strongest subject. I'd really appreciate help on this one. Thanks!

Comment: The mathematical equation is Rate = Portion / Base. In your case, you have 130 (portion) and a base of 220 (total answers).

Answer (score 0):

percentage for YES

```
 Yes % = (total answers of yes / total ansers)*100
    $yes = 130;
    $no = 90;
    $totals = $yes+$no;
    $yes_per = ($yes/$totals) *100;
```

percentage for No

```
 No % = (total answers of No / total ansers)*100

    $no_per = ($no/$totals) *100
```

Comment: What, if there are no total answers?

Comment: In that case try catch can be used

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do this

```
<?php

$yes = 130;
$no = 90;

$total_votes = $yes+$no;

if($total_votes > 0){
    $yes_percentage = ($yes/$total_votes) *100;
    $no_percentage = ($no/$total_votes) *100
}
else{
    $yes_percentage = 0; 
    $no_percentage = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get total count.

```
$total = $yes + $no;
```

Then, if you want percentage of yes.

```
($yes / $total) * 100;
```

Comment: What, if $yes = 0 and $no = 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
TotalParticipants=130+90=220
YesVotedParticipants=130
NoVotedParticipants=90

YesVotedPaticipants percent(%)= (YesVotedParticipants/TotalParticipants)*100
                                 = (130/220)*100 =59.09 %

NoVotedPaticipants percent(%)= (NoVotedParticipants/TotalParticipants)*100
                                 = (90/220)*100 =40.90 %
```